# Is there a #define for C99?

Tags: c, macros, c99

I want to do something in C99 one way, otherwise to perform it another way. What is the `#define` to check for?

```
#ifdef C99
...
#else
...
#endif
```

Comment: Terminology nitpick: What newbies call a #define, the gurus call a *macro* or (*macro identifier* when they specifically refer to the thingy that should be replaced).

Answer (score 39, accepted):

There is not an specific `#define` value. Just check `__STDC_VERSION__` and define it yourself! ;-)

```
#if __STDC_VERSION__ >= 199901L
/* C99 code */
#define C99
#else
/* Not C99 code */
#endif


#ifdef C99
/*My code in C99 format*/
#else
/*My code in C99 format*/
#endif
```

**EDIT:** A more general snippet, [from here](http://predef.sourceforge.net/prestd.html). I've just changed the defined names, just in case you'll use them a lot on the code:

```
#if defined(__STDC__)
# define C89
# if defined(__STDC_VERSION__)
#  define C90
#  if (__STDC_VERSION__ >= 199409L)
#   define C94
#  endif
#  if (__STDC_VERSION__ >= 199901L)
#   define C99
#  endif
#  if (__STDC_VERSION__ >= 201112L)
#   define C11
#  endif
# endif
#endif
```

Answer (score 24):

```
#if __STDC_VERSION__ == 199901L
/* C99 */
#else
/* not C99 */
#endif
```

Change `==` to `>=` if you want to test for C99 and later.