# Simple program won't compile in C

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-construction

Okay I know right off the bat this is going to be a stupid question, but I am not seeing why this simple C program is not compiling.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
typdef struct CELL *LIST;
struct CELL {
    int element;
    LIST next;
};
main() {
    struct CELL *value;
    printf("Hello, World!");
}
```

I am new to C programming, not to programming in general, but to C. I am familiar with Objective-C, Java, Matlab, and a few others, but for some reason I can not figure this one out. I am trying to compile it using GCC in OS X if that makes a difference. Thanks for your help!

The error message I am getting is

```
functionTest.c:5: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before ‘LIST’
functionTest.c:7: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘struct’
```

Comment: Did you try to compile it with `gcc -Wall -g yourprog.c -o yourbinary` ?

Comment: Generally speaking, reading the error message is the best way to figure out why.  If you want us to help, perhaps you should post the error message.

Comment: I was just getting ready to do that actually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most importantly: You have misspelled typedef.

Then, at least these days, we normally add a return type to main, like so:

```
int main()
```

Also, main is supposed to return the exit status, so:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct CELL *LIST;

struct CELL {
  int element;
  LIST next;
};

int main() {
  struct CELL *value;
  printf("Hello, World!\n");
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yeah I am really stupid and did not realize I was misspelling typedef. I feel like a complete idiot. It is one of those times when you write something and stare at it for hours, and someone else comes along, looks at it for a second and immediately see it. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @MZimmerman6, I got this on GCC: *error: 'typdef' does not name a type*. That's pretty self-explanatory ;)

Comment: GCC did not say that to me. Don't know why

Answer (score 2):

The main reason is that you typoed `typedef` as `typdef`. However, there are a couple other things you should do:

- Add `return 0;` to the end of `main()`.
- Change the signature of `main` to `int main(void)`

Comment: @ArmenTsirunyan, I've never looked at that in the C spec, but GCC complains about it for C code, so I presume it is. I'm aware that it's an implicit `return 0;` from main if you leave it out in C++.

Comment: @ArmenTsirunyan, Looking at C11, in 5.1.2.2.3/1 it says: *...reaching the } that terminates the
main function returns a value of 0. ...* I'm not sure why GCC is picky about it in C if that's the case.

Comment: Both C99 and C11 have an implicit `return 0;` right before the terminating brace of the main() function. C89 doesn't. In C89 the statement is required; in C99 and C11 it is good-form.

Comment: @pmg, Thanks, that clears it up. If you happen to know, does LWS use C89? I'm not experienced with C, but it seems as if it was older sometimes.

Comment: @chris: you can use Standard macros to identify the version in use. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2115886/25324). For C2011 (I hate to call it C11) the `__STDC_VERSION__` is `201112L`.

Comment: @pmg, Well, after trying that and looking around a bit when it wasn't defined at all, I guess LWS has no -std= flag passed in, so early C90 or thereabouts.

Answer (score 2):

Did you try to compile it with `gcc -Wall -g yourprog.c -o yourbinary` ?

I'm getting:

```
yourprog.c:3:8: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'struct'
yourprog.c:6:5: error: unknown type name 'LIST'
yourprog.c:8:1: warning: return type defaults to 'int' [-Wreturn-type]
yourprog.c: In function 'main':
yourprog.c:9:18: warning: unused variable 'value' [-Wunused-variable]
yourprog.c:11:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
```

and you mispelled `typedef` and you should change the signature of `main` and add a `return 0;` inside.

By the way, I find your `typedef` very poor taste. I suggest to code (like Gtk does) something like `typedef struct CELL CELL_t` and declare `CELL_t* value = NULL.` because you really want to remember that `value` is a pointer to `CELL_t`. In particular, I hate typedef-s like `typedef struct CELL* CELL_ptr;` because I find very imporrtant (for readability reasons) to quickly understand what is a pointer and what is not a pointer.

Actually I would rather suggest

```
 struct cell_st;
 typedef struct cell_st cell_t;
 cell_t *value = NULL;
```

(I do like initializing all pointers to NULL).

Answer (score 0):

Add a return in your main function

Comment: While it is indeed a good idea to have it, the code will actually compile even without that return.

Comment: @perh: Not without issuing two warnings about it (with `-Wall`)